# Shortcode to output category description by passing ID

Tags: functions, shortcode

I have this shortcode function:

```
function category_description_output($atts) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'catID' => '16'
  ), $atts, 'categorydescription' );

  return category_description( $atts['catID'] );
}
add_shortcode('categorydescription', 'category_description_output');
```

My shortcodes look like this:
[categorydescription catID=16]
[categorydescription catID=17]
[categorydescription catID=18]
[categorydescription catID=19]

But they are all outputing the category description for the default ID of 16.

Comment: What happens if you do `[categorydescription catID="17"]` with the catID in quotes

Comment: I get the same outcome if I added " " around the id

Comment: Can you try the following in your function, can you replace the return line with `return $atts['catID'];` and make sure it is returning the correct ID?

Comment: It's only returning the default ID of 16.

Comment: In the WordPress admin, if you click on the text view where the shortcodes are located, are there any special characters or spaces within the shortcode? Can you copy the shortcode from the text view and add to the to the question?

Comment: No there are no special characters used, here is a screenshot: [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/cnyna8lbpeems6s/Capture2.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the editor screen where you add the shortcode

Comment: It's being added through the Elementor visual editor.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of how it looks in Elementor

Comment: Here is the screenshot from inside the visual editor: https://www.dropbox.com/s/crx6ufpvtxiona0/elementor-shortcode.PNG?dl=0